# Any shortcut to providing identical ostream and wostream stream operators?

Tags: c++, stl, googletest, visual-c++-2013

I want to provide ostream<< and wostream<< operators for a class, which are identical other than one being widestream and the other not.

Is there some trickery to do this which is ugly than just copy-pasting and making the necessary tweaks?

For reference, this is necessary because we use wostream as standard, but Google-test's EXPECT_PRED3 fails compilation when no `ostream<<` is provided, even though other macros happily work with `ostream` or `wostream`.

My actual code looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
...
public:
  friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& s, const MyClass& o)
  {
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: Use a template for the overload function with `std::basic_ostream`? Of course, if there's any kind of special handling required depending on character type then there's no choice, you have to write to different functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg unless special character type handling is extremelly non-trivial (and I beleive this is rarely the case), it can be moved to a separate specialized/overloaded function and called from the templated `operator <<`.

Comment: In at least one case, I literally went through and deleted the 'w' in `wostream`, nothing else.

Comment: You can even define `template<typename Os> Os& operator<<(Os& os, const MyType&)` and work with ostream, wostream, or any stream-like-but-not-quite class that exposes some minimal stream-like interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::ostream` and `std::wostream` are just specializations of a template class [`std::basic_ostream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/). Writing a templated `operator <<` shall solve your problem. Here's an example:

```
struct X { int i; };

template <typename Char, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits> & operator << (std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits> & out, X const & x)
{
    return out << "This is X: " << x.i << std::endl;
}
```

As pointed out in comments, you can go even further and parametrize your `operator <<` by any class that exposes some stream-like interface:

```
template <typename OStream>
OStream & operator << (OStream & out, X const & x)
{
    return out << "This is X: " << x.i << std::endl;
}
```